# Add a link on top of html elements (React)

Tags: javascript, react

I have a "meeting radar" on my SharePoint witch is build using react I think and I wish to upgrade. Unfortunatly, even though I am starting to have a correct js level, I dont understand this code and the person that did wrote it is no longer around or commented it.

So this radar (see picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ahDysp3Jv2y1xvPNfA6gpYZlBnNprNKX) is displaying flashing points with the name of the meetings that the script get from a SP list.

I want to either make each displayed meeting a clickable link to the SP list item or a simple link on top of the complete radar to the SP list.

I just dont manage to understand the code below and were I schould try to build an onclick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" description="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\radar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/mySite/SiteAssets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
 <div className="app-container" id="appContainer"></div>

 <script src="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\react\react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\react\react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\react\babel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\react\axios.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\sites\mySite\SiteAssets\react\bluebird.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

class ArticleListContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : []
    }}

  componentDidMount() {

    var config = {
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    };
        axios.get("http://my.company.corp/sites/mySite/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Termin%20Radar')/items?$filter=Priority%20eq%20%27High%27",config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.d.results);

        this.setState({
          data:response.data.d.results
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error
        });
      });

      //response.data.d.results.push(response.data.d.results[0]);

  }

  //<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onclick="EditLink2(this,117);return false;" onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://mycompany.corp/sites/mySite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7B6AE8DD28%2DD469%2D457D%2DA8E4%2DFABC3D2A5DA4%7D&amp;ID=1&amp;ContentTypeID=0x010300B4B752E2E0C4D84CB26B1DCB7D394445" target="_self" DragId="0">Type A+ Full Scale Evac Test, Workstream Slides</a>

  //href="http://mycompany.corp/sites/mySite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7B6AE8DD28%2DD469%2D457D%2DA8E4%2DFABC3D2A5DA4%7D&amp;ID=1&amp;ContentTypeID=0" + {article.ContentTypeId} + """
  render() {

      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map( function( article, i ){
               return(
             //react.js, not far from solution with onClick
             //<div className="target" key={article.Id} onClick={article.ContentTypeId}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
             //<div onClick={article.ContentTypeId} className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
            <div className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>  
        )})}
        </div>
      )
  }  
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="grid">
        <div className="radar"><div ></div>
          <div className="axis"></div>
          <div className="concentric-circles"></div>
          <div className="pacman"></div>
          <div className="targets">
            <ArticleListContainer/>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anybody could give me pointer on how to add these dynamic links, that would be great. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I am not that much aware of React, but I can help you creating dynamic link list item or for list url

Comment: Any help is welcome. I played in the part with "{this.state.data.map( function( article, i ){" trying to build the link here, since it is the part bulding the text to display, but not chance yet. I dont mind rewritting a part of the code nt with react, with I dont master anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, the answer was pretty easy actually.
My problem is that I could not get how to concatenate 2 {variable} inside my url. Turns out I just had to write {var1 + var2}

```
  render() {
      console.log('in render');
  console.log(this.data);
  var listitemURL= "http://.../sites/.../Lists/Termin%20Radar/DispForm.aspx?ID="
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map( function( article, i ){
            return(
                //var listitemURL= "http://.../sites/.../Lists/Termin%20Radar/DispForm.aspx?ID="+{article.ID};
                //<div className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>  
                <div className="target" key={article.Id}><a href={listitemURL+article.ID}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></a></div>  
            )})}
        </div>
      )
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic list item url:

```
render() {

  return (
  <a href="http://my.company.corp/sites/mySite/Lists/Termin Radar/">
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map( function( article, i ){
           return(
         //react.js, not far from solution with onClick
         //<div className="target" key={article.Id} onClick={article.ContentTypeId}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
         //<div onClick={article.ContentTypeId} className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
          var listitemURL= "http://my.company.corp/sites/mySite/Lists/Termin Radar/DispForm.aspx?ID="+{article.ID};
      <div className="target" key={article.Id}><a href={listitemURL}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></a></div>  
    )})}
    </div>
    </a>
  )
 }
```

For List URL, link below in href attribute directly on main outer div of radar

```
render() {

  return (
  <a href="http://my.company.corp/sites/mySite/Lists/Termin Radar/">
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map( function( article, i ){
           return(
         //react.js, not far from solution with onClick
         //<div className="target" key={article.Id} onClick={article.ContentTypeId}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
         //<div onClick={article.ContentTypeId} className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>
        <div className="target" key={article.Id}><span className="text">{article.Title}</span></div>  
    )})}
    </div>
    </a>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for these feedback, I am getting near to the goal I think. Nevertheless, in case1, adding a variable in the "return(" seems to create a blocking point: on my page, nothing is displayed. I tried to put some console.log there but same results. It is not loading the sciript